# Access Denied Error within Advanced Search page for the Site Collection Administrator?

Tags: search

On the bottom of Advanced Search page in my Client's SharePoint intranet, there is a link: "Improve your searches with search tips". Exactly like this: (http://www.wssdemo.com/search/Pages/advanced.aspx).

Now my problem is: When I click on the link search tips, I get the Error message:

Access Denied 
You are currently signed in as: ...
Sign in as a different user

The problem is that my account is a Site Collection Administrator and I do have all the rights and privileges inside the environment.

I tried the URL (http://Site URL/search/_layouts/help.aspx?Lcid=1033&Key=WSSEndUser_SearchTips&ShowNav=true), and it gives me the same Access Denied Error Message.

Could you please help me out on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried to remove and re-add the Search web part and still having the same issue.
Somehow, It is a problem that related to permissions.

 

Any idea how to grant permissions to users and allow them to open the MS Online Help when they click on "Improve your searches with search tips" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues and found it was easier to modify where the link was navigating to and provide my own search tips link..via following script

It is possible to modify the destination to be something of your choosing by inserting the following script within the hidden content editor part.

Given html on the page like the following (and a reference to the jquery library somewhere on the page)

```
<span id="ctl00_m_g_62c29441_082b_45bb_8f70_500308b27553_ASB_TS_SRCH_1">Improve your searches with <ahref='javascript:HelpWindowKey("WSSEndUser_SearchTips")'> search tips </a></span>



The following script will change the url to be set to http://www.yahoo.com for example.

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       var lnk = $('span[id*=SRCH] > a');
       lnk.attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com'); //changes link to yahoo
       lnk.attr('target','new'); //when link is clicked it will open a new browser window
   });

</script>
```